# Regex to match between 2 and 5 characters, one of which must be alphabetic

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm not great with regex and the following has me stumped.

I need to find all the matches in a string that are between 2 and 5 characters [A-Z0-9] only, and must contain at least one alphabetic character [A-Z]

So

```
A1 - Match
AAA - Match
AAAAAA - No Match
A1234 - Match
123 - No Match
A123A - Match
A - No Match
1 - No Match
A1B2C3 - No Match
```

I have tried this:

```
([A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*){2,5}
```

But it doesnt limit the total length of the match to between 2 and 5 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(?=\d*[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{2,5}\b
\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\b)[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/rk0EPf/4) and the [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/rk0EPf/3). Details:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=\d*[A-Z])` - after zero or more digits, there must be an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\b)` - there must be 2 to 5 alnum chars up to the word boundary
- `[A-Z0-9]*` - zero or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[A-Z\d]{2,5}` - two to five uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `\b` - word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pq7g5J):

```py
import re
text = "A1 AAA....A1234!!!!~A123A abc,AAAAAA,123,A,1,A1B2C3"
print(re.findall(r'\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\b)[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b', text))
# => ['A1', 'AAA', 'A1234', 'A123A']
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to find multiple occurrences within a string so if I use ^ and $ the above won't work. If I remove them it works but matches partial parts of the string.

A1 AAA AAAAAA A1234 123 A123A A 1 A1B2C3 

results in the 1st 5 character of AAAAAA being a match when I would like that substring to not be a match

Comment: @TheWelshDragon Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
`^([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,4}|[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z0-9]{,3}|[A-Z0-9]{1,2}[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{,3}|[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z0-9])$`